type object 'my model' has no attribute 'CHOICES' after running 'migrate'
so here in my migration file i have this function :
  def populate_categories(apps, schema_editor):
    CategoryModel = apps.get_model('app_l3', 'CategoryModel')
    for name, desc in CategoryModel.CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        CategoryModel.objects.create(category_name=name, description=desc)

this is for auto populating my database, and the model is this
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('hardware', 'Hardware'),
    ('software', 'Software'),
    ('network', 'Network'),
    ('printer', 'Printer'),
    ('phone', 'Phone'),
    ('laptop', 'Laptop'),
)

category_name = models.CharField(max_length = 150,unique=True,primary_key=True,choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
description = models.TextField()
category_creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True,blank=True)

so after i tried to run py manage.py migrate i got this error :
for name, desc in CategoryModel.CATEGORY_CHOICES:
AttributeError: type object 'CategoryModel' has no attribute 'CATEGORY_CHOICES'

so how i could fix it .. and is there other ways to auto populate with predefined choices

Did you define choices as a property in your model. So use CategoryModel.choices instead in populate_categories.

@SunderamDubey no , my model is the same as above , i only have name , desc, and date
